# Angular 6. Subject не обновляет subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observer

Есть сервис и два компонента, общение компонентов задумано через сервис и   Subject. Но  subscribe отправляет в компонент, которй должен получать данные, пустой массив до того, как компонент который отправляет данные это сделает, а когда данные всеже уйдут - ничего не происходит.

Компонент из которого данные уходят в сервис.

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { FilterService } from '../services/filter.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css'],
  providers: [FilterService, DataService]
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private filterService: FilterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForms();
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  submit() {
    // Отправкаданных в сервис. Который отправляет результат работы функции далее ... subscription.next() 
    this.filterService.getFilteredItems(this.myForm.value);
  }

}
```

Сервис который обратвает данные и формирует сабскрибшены.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilterService {
  private dataSubject: Subject<any>;
  private dataFromService: any;
  public dataSubjectSubscription$;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataFromService = false;
    this.dataSubject = new Subject<any>();
    // Изначально был вариант без this.dataSubjectSubscription$, вместо этого 
    // я использовал метод, которй возвращал обсервер this.dataSubject.asObservable();
    this.dataSubjectSubscription$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public getFilteredItems(filters) {
    this.dataService.getItemsData().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSubject.next(this.filterer(data, filters));
    });

  }
  private filterer(data, filter) {
    return data.filter(item => {
      if (item.city !== filter.city) {
        return false;
      }
      return (
        filter.category.includes(item.category) ||
        filter.price[0] <= item.price &&
        filter.price[1] >= item.price
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Код компонента который принимает данные и где происходит подписка на сабджект.

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { FilterService } from '../services/filter.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-items',
  templateUrl: './items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./items.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService, FilterService]
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  private dataArray: Array<any>;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private filterService: FilterService) {
    this.dataService.getItemsData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.dataArray = [...data];
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.filterService.dataSubjectSubscription$.subscribe((data) =>  {
      this.dataArray = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Пробовал использовать `ehaviorSubject` вместо `Subject`, но ничего не даело результатов. Буду примного благодарен за помощь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вы конечно тут намудрили... :-) Если я все правильно понял, то при вызове `FilterService.prototype.getFilteredItems` делается запрос на API, возвращаются какие-то данные и после этого вы хотите известить другой компонент. Убираем ненужное из `FilterService`:

```
export class FilterService {
    public data$ = new Subject<any>(); <--- нам нужен только этот генератор событий

    public getFilteredItems(filters) {
        this.dataService.getItemsData().subscribe((data) => {
            this.data$.next(this.filterer(data, filters));
        });
    }
```

В компоненте который слушает данный поток, подписываемся на `data$`:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators/takeUntil';

export class ItemsComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

    private dataArray: any[] = [];

    constructor(
        private dataService: DataService,
        private filterService: FilterService
    ) {
        this.dataService.getItemsData().subscribe((data) => {
            this.dataArray = [...data];
        });

        this.filterService.data$.asObservable().pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroy$)
        ).subscribe((data) => {
            this.dataArray = data;
        });
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }
}
```

`asObservable` - это шаблон, который позволяет ограничить возможности `Subject` только `Observable` интерфейсом. `BehaviorSubject` - также является генератором событий, но вдобавок он всегда кеширует последнее значение.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, Вы верно пометили, только это данные из формы :) Но не суть важно. Попробовал этот способ, но увы. Subscribe инициализируется в компоненте при его загрузке и далее не реагирует на работу сервиса, хотя в сервисе все отрабатывает. Могу предположить, что проблема в том, что инициализация идет до того как что-то передали в next(), так как консол логи внутри subscribe отрабатывают, но тогда я не понимаю зачем это вот все нужно.

Comment: вы неправильно понимаете работу потоков, могу предположить вы забежали вперед паровоза с изучением rxjs, без знания паттерна паб-саб тут дров не нарубишь... :-( subscribe это не инициализация, а колбек в subscribe не отработает пока не вызовется next, значит что-то в вашем коде дергает next, что делает getItemsData?

Comment: этот метод собирает изначальные данные, которые показывать, а проблема в том, что бы вывести значения отфильтрованные.

Comment: Если отследить в дебаггере, то можно увидеть, что до data$ выполнение так и не доходит. Может ли быть так, что сборщик считает этот сабджек не используемым и сносит его?

Comment: нет))) этот объект живет столько же, сколько и инстанс сервиса, вы говорите что до `data$` дело не доходит, так может проблема в getItemsData? у меня в данный момент такое подозрение на 95%

Comment: Я в целях эксперимента убрал из сервиса все, оставил только сабджект и попробовал передать просто строку и ничего не сработало. Создал новый проект, где попробовал сделать примерно тоже самое, что и в этом - все работает. Могли ли какие-то зависимости так повлиять на rxjs или ангулар в целом?

Comment: Спасибо, все решил. Правда не могу понять - почему.

Answer (score -1):

Я не знаю по какой причине, но проблема была в том, что я указал сервисы как провайдеры в компонентах. Убрав из компонентов `providers: [DataService, FilterService]` все заработало.

Comment: потому что каждый компонент инжектил инстанс сервиса из своего инжектора, в итоге получалось 2 компонента - 4 инстанса сервисов (Data + Filter), DI в Angular описан на первых страницах документации